# Adding a Schedule Task Module for WPF Window Application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, command-line, scheduled-tasks

I have a small program which converts doc file from specified folder to pdf and XPS format using the printer driver available in the local PC.

Now I need to add a scheduler to this program which runs as per scheduled by the user taking parameters like folder_where_doc_files, Destination_Folder, Date_Time to schedule, whether daily, etc, etc.. in the background.

It's a WPF C# window application. The user is requesting to use the command line to schedule the task.

I am unable to analyze how to proceed further.

I checked a few links where "schtaks" command can be used to create a task. How to send my desired parameters to it.
even if I do then my application will start in the background. How to initiate a conversion process like any events on form load, etc, etc..

I am really confused, Please clarify this confusion

Comment: Can you install a windows service on client machine?

Comment: Yes. I can install. To be precise, Its already installed. The scheduling part is the Update for the program

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible design would be

1- Create a console application which takes input from the user and store it either locally or on the server

2- Create a windows service that will check through your storage (Local/Server) periodically for the next run.

3- After each run save the last run time in local / server to calculate the next schedule.

The scheduled task requires a user/pwd to be stored in the scheduled task itself and needs to be updated each time the user changes the system password.

Comment: As i mentioned its already a WPF Window Application and is currently being used by the client. The scheduling part is just the update which is added to the existing application